# É possível separar o valor do item JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

Digamos que eu tenha um objeto assim:

```
{
  "parametros": {
    "carteira": "RG", 
    "taxaboleto": "0.00", 
    "multa": "0.00", 
    "juros": "0.00"
  }
}
```

É possível que eu consiga extrair o nome do item do objeto? Por exemplo, o item "carteira": "RG", se eu imprimir na tela como `{{parametros.carteira}}` (em Vue) eu consigo imprimir o valor, mas e se eu precisar do nome `'carteira'` para ser impresso? Como eu faço pra extrair?

Levem em consideração que eu não sei qual o objeto que está chegando, pode ser que seja dinâmico os itens que irão aparecendo...

Comment: Tem que ser em vue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode-se usar o `Object.keys()`, onde ele retornará as chaves do objeto, ao invés dos valores. Fiz um exemplo bem simples abaixo:

**HelloWorld.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="stackoverflow">
    <div v-for="(parametro, key) in parametrosKeys" :key="key">{{ parametro }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { parametros } from './parametros'

export default {
  name: 'Stackoverflow',
  data: () => ({
    parametros
  }),
  computed: {
    parametrosKeys () {
      return Object.keys(this.parametros)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**parametros.json**

```
{
  "parametros": {
    "carteira": "RG",
    "taxaboleto": "0.00",
    "multa": "0.00",
    "juros": "0.00"
  }
}
```

Note que no exemplo eu faço uma `computed` que apenas retorna as chaves usando o `Object.keys`, mas isto poderia ser realizada diretamente. O exemplo acima retornaria todas as chaves assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]